# Hash sorting alphabetiacly in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

I have the following hash.

```
h = {
    "31d2fcd5-aec0-438d-895c-806fd0358c23"=>{"name"=>"q", 'database'=>'mysql'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d12f8c1"=>{"name"=>"Qwerty", 'database'=>'H2'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121993"=>{"name"=>"b", 'database'=>'postgresql'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121994"=>{"name"=>"B", 'database'=>'oracle'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121995"=>{"name"=>"Apple", 'database'=>'sqlite3'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d521996"=>{"name"=>"a", 'database'=>'mariadb'},
    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d1k1996"=>{"name"=>"A", 'database'=>'mongodb'}
}
```

After sorting I would like to see it in the following form

```
h = {
     "31d2fcd5-aec0-438d-895c-806fd0358c23"=>{"name"=>"a", 'database'=>'mariadb'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d12f8c1"=>{"name"=>"A", 'database'=>'mongodb'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121993"=>{"name"=>"Apple", 'database'=>'sqlite3'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121994"=>{"name"=>"b", 'database'=>'postgresql'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121995"=>{"name"=>"B", 'database'=>'oracle'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d521996"=>{"name"=>"q", 'database'=>'mysql'},
     "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d1k1996"=>{"name"=>"Qwerty", 'database'=>'H2'}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you have the requirement of a specific order then a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) might not be the right data structure for you, because hash tables are an unordered data structure. Even if Ruby's hash has a stable sorting since version 1.9.3, you should not depend on this, because you would have to manually reorder each time you add an item.

Comment: My ruby version is 1.8.7

Comment: You might want to elaborate why want to sort that hash. Then we might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: The version of Ruby you are using is crucial, so you need to edit your question to mention it there. Don't count on readers seeing all the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You can't. See the docs about [hashes in Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html):

> The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order.

In Ruby 1.8.7 hashes are not ordered. It is not even guaranteed that the order matches the order in which the keys were inserted (like it would be in Ruby 1.9+).

That said: You will have to use a different data structure, like an array for example. Arrays can be sorted by its first value and they would keep that order.

Btw: Ruby 1.8.7 is outdated more many years already (its successor [Ruby 1.9 was released six years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/)). Ruby 1.8.7 is missing some interesting features, doesn't get security updates anymore and many gems dropped support for this old version. I advise to update to at least Ruby 2.2+

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in RubyDocs:

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys
>   were inserted.

So you need to create new hash for your purposes:

```
h.to_a.sort_by{|s| s[1]['name']}.to_h

{
  "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d1k1996"=>{"name"=>"A", "database"=>"mongodb"}, 
  "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121995"=>{"name"=>"Apple", "database"=>"sqlite3"}, 
  "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121994"=>{"name"=>"B", "database"=>"oracle"}, 
  "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d12f8c1"=>{"name"=>"Qwerty", "database"=>"H2"}, 
  "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d521996"=>{"name"=>"a", "database"=>"mariadb"}, 
 "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121993"=>{"name"=>"b", "database"=>"postgresql"}, 
 "31d2fcd5-aec0-438d-895c-806fd0358c23"=>{"name"=>"q", "database"=>"mysql"}
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that produces the order that the OP requested.

Comment: Mikhail Chuprynski your written code is working on the ruby online redactors, but is not working for my PC. By the way my ruby version is 1.8.7.

Comment: @KhachaturSaribekyan you can use `Hash[h.to_a.sort_by{|s| s[1]['name']}]`

Comment: Since the OP is still on Ruby 1.8.7. non of the above will guarantee a certain order.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby v.1.9.3+,

```
h.sort_by { |_,v| [v["name"][0].downcase, v["name"]] }.to_h
  #=> {"69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d1k1996"=>{"name"=>"A", "database"=>"mongodb"},
  #    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121995"=>{"name"=>"Apple", "database"=>"sqlite3"},
  #    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d521996"=>{"name"=>"a", "database"=>"mariadb"},
  #    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121994"=>{"name"=>"B", "database"=>"oracle"},
  #    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d121993"=>{"name"=>"b", "database"=>"postgresql"},
  #    "69a05dea-d767-44b7-b40c-f76d0d12f8c1"=>{"name"=>"Qwerty", "database"=>"H2"},
  #    "31d2fcd5-aec0-438d-895c-806fd0358c23"=>{"name"=>"q", "database"=>"mysql"}}
```

See the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how Ruby orders arrays, which determines their sorted order.

My result differs from yours in the secondary sort.  Your primary sort is

```
["q", "Qwerty", "b", "B", "Apple", "a", "A"].sort_by { |s| s[0].downcase }
  #=> ["a", "Apple", "A", "B", "b", "q", "Qwerty"]
```

which is fine, but your secondary sort on strings beginning with `"a"` or `"A"`, which you want to be

```
["a", "A", "Apple"]
```

is neither

```
["a", "Apple", "A"].sort
  # => ["A", "Apple", "a"]
```

nor

```
["a", "Apple", "A"].sort.reverse
  #=> ["a", "Apple", "A"]
```

so this begs the question, "what is your secondary sort criterion"?